# Discrepancy in the value stored in two variables having the same integral part

Tags: c++, int, double, type-conversion

I was trying to find the cube root of 10^12 and used the following code in c++. To my surprise, the value returned was different . Can anyone help me with this problem.

Output: 10000 9999

```
    int y;
    double x=pow(1000000000000, 1./3);
    double r=floor(x);
    y=(int)r;
    cout<<x<<" ";
    cout<<y;
```

Comment: Is this a homework question or something ? We seem to be suffering from a rash of questions about `pow(x, 1./3)` lately...

Answer (score 2):

Your `floor` operation is the issue here. What if the returned value is actually (due to precision errors) x = 9999.999? `floor(x)` would return 9999 while `cout << x` directly prints the floating point number based on it's internal precision setting, so `cout << x` does implicit rounding which is why 10000 is displayed there.

Try rounding x properly to an int by doing this:

```
int y;
double x=pow(1000000000000, 1./3);
y=(int)(x+0.5); //Proper rounding
cout<<x<<" ";
cout<<y;
return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double x=pow(1000000000000, 1./3);
```

is just bad 1/3 can not be displayed with double.

when working with double result are always interesting to say the least. 0.001 + 0.001 may just be 0.0

Comment: "[I]s just bad", "displayed with double", "always interesting", "may just be 0.0" is an assorted set of misplaced phrases.